# How to check if two paths are the same in npm?

Tags: npm, path

In npm path module, people use `path.join` because it handles cross platform slashes and extra slashes. However, is there a way to compare two paths to see if its the same folder in a cross platform way?

I want to avoid situations where it ends up comparing `/foo/bar` to `\foo\bar` and says its not the same but it really is.

Thanks

Comment: [path-equal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-equal) author here. :)

Answer (score 6):

I've solved this by using `path.resolve` on both the paths I want to compare. This makes paths absolute against `process.cwd()` and solves the backslash/forwardslash issue. It also resolves `../../a/b/` paths.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer doesn't take into account that paths on win32, unlike most other platforms, are case-insensitive. The following should do the trick:

```
function pathsAreEqual(path1, path2) {
  path1 = path.resolve(path1);
  path2 = path.resolve(path2);
  if (process.platform == "win32")
    return path1.toLowerCase() === path2.toLowerCase();
  return path1 === path2;
}
```

Testing:

```
path.resolve("C:\\Users\\user") == path.resolve("C:\\Users\\USER") // false
pathsAreEqual("C:\\Users\\user", "C:\\Users\\USER") // true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`path.relative`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#pathrelativefrom-to) to check if both path are the same, if both path are same then this API will return empty string. Note that it will also work for case-insensitive path platforms like Windows.

Comment: very cool, that did the trick!